# Increasing range of FM transmitter

Tags: signal, radio, transmitter, frequency-modulation

What things impact to range of FM signal? If I increse length of antenna would signal range increase?

I would like to increase the signal range of [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-si4713-fm-radio-transmitter-with-rds-rdbs-support/test-and-usage?view=all) project. Is that possible? Do I need more power or longer antenna? What kind of antenna is best for long range?

Comment: Silicon Labs addresses transmit antenna length in AN383 page 55. Their discussion of short antenna lengths between 6cm - 15cm is likely influenced by FCC requirements of radiated RF power. You can probably radiate a strong signal with RF matching networks to a resonant antenna, but risk violating FCC rules. Silicon Labs has carefully avoided describing optimum **radiated power** in their app note, and only describe matching to a short non-optimum antenna. The transmitting chip includes on-board capacitance that can be programmed to "tune" your antenna for best output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that the device TX power on this gizmo is limited to comply with FCC Part 15 Subpart J rules. Modifying it to boost its power would put you at odds with that.

That all said, an FM 'Yagi' antenna will concentrate the power in a directional pattern and increase the range, at the expense of overall coverage.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the true answer by @hacktastical, there is a big issue.

With the 1 meter wire antenna that comes with it you get a range of 30 feet, about the same as basic Bluetooth. Extend antenna in increments of a meter to get more range, but if it can be picked up over a 100 feet/33 meters away, you could have issues with the FCC.

Neighbors who listen to FM could complain about interference from *somewhere*, and the FCC will investigate. To avoid this un-funny scenario I would not make the antenna over 2 meters/6 feet long. The signal MUST stay confined to your own property.